# Drupal: How to update display fields after changing the database?

Tags: drupal

I added a new column "approval" into the table 'files'. When i go to views and wanted to add the approval field, it's not there.

What can i do to let it appear?

Answer (score 0):

Create little module with hooks of views, that describe your field